# Defining Parameters in JavaScript reduce

Tags: javascript, parameters, reduce

I am looking at this reduce function in JavaScript . . .

```
var colors = ['red', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'green'];

var distinctColors = colors.reduce(
    (distinct, color) =>
        (distinct.indexOf(color) != -1) ?
            distinct : 
            [...distinct, color],
    []
)
```

I understand that the callback function is called once for each item in the `colors` array, searching for the `color` string in `distinct` and simply returning the array if it is found, and adding `color` to `distinct` if not found.

What I do not understand is how the function parameters `(distict, color)` are defined as the empty array and each color.

Does JavaScript automatically assume that `distinct` is the array because I call `distinct.indexOf(color)`??

Comment: See that last part, that `,[]` - the second parameter you pass to `reduce` is the type of `distinct` - per the docs: *[Optional] Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce on an empty array without an initial value is an error.* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: so the second parameter passed to a reduce function is default, yes I understand that.  But how does the callback function assume that `distinct` is that default parameter and not `color`?

Comment: The first parameter of the callback is always the default value - it doesn't shift around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.
>   from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

So it is just an accumulator, or a "current state" value. For example, let's find the maximum value of an array:

```js
let values=[4,5,6,77,8,12,0,9];

let max=values.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  console.log(`comparing ${acc} and ${curr}`); 
  return Math.max(acc,curr)
  },0);

console.log(max);
```

This code just stores (accumulates) the maximum value found in each step, and then returns it.

Answer (score 2):

First from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) a quick description:

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
> element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single
> value.

#### Practically:

`arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])` where callback takes `(accumulator, currentValue)` as arguments. The accumulator is the holding array for your reduced values, currentValue is the value of the current array index you are comparing.

#### In your example:

```
// Reducer function, returns either the current state of the accumulator
// or returns a new array instance of the accumulator with the new value
const getDistinctColors = (accumulator, currentValue) => ((accumulator.indexOf(currentValue) !== -1) ? accumulator : [ ...accumulator, currentValue ]);
  
// define color group
let colors = ['red', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'green'];
// reduce color group (initialize with empty array [])
let distinctColors = colors.reduce(getDistinctColors, []);
```