# Why using Math.max as a parameter does not work on this scenario?

Tags: javascript, lambda

I was answering a [question related to Array.reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922864/defining-parameters-in-javascript-reduce/45922993#) by using Math.max in my example and I found something that I don't understand:

This works:

```js
let values=[4,5,6,77,8,12,0,9];

let max=values.reduce((acc,curr) => Math.max(acc,curr),0);

console.log(max);
```

But if I try something like this:

```js
let values=[4,5,6,77,8,12,0,9];

let max=values.reduce(Math.max,0);

console.log(max);
```

It returns NaN.

I thought that the context was the reason, so I wrote the following:

```js
let max=Math.max;
console.log(max(2,5));
```

But it worked as expected!

What am I missing? [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) that:

> If at least one of the arguments cannot be converted to a number, NaN
>   is returned.

Comment: The `reduce` method gives the callback function four arguments. The fourth argument is the array itself. An array is not a number. Hence, you're getting `NaN`.

Comment: As a sidenode, it should be noted that you don't need `reduce` at all, you could just call `Math.max` with `apply` instead

Comment: @adeneo In ES6 you could simply do `Math.max(...values)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're missing is that the callback to `reduce` has *more parameters* than just the accumulator and current array value. It actually has 4.

See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Description

The **four parameters**:

```
accumulator
currentValue
currentIndex
array (a reference to the array itself)
```

The problem is the fourth parameter, it's the array itself that `reduce` was called on. `Math.max` can't handle arrays, so it returns `NaN`.

EDIT: instead, you can use the `apply` method or the new spread operator!

```
let values = [4,5,6,77,8,12,0,9];
let max = Math.max.apply(null, values);
let maxAnotherWay = Math.max(...values);
```

**OR**, if you happen to be using Lodash, the `_.ary` method lets you wrap functions in another function that limits its *arity*:

```
let values = [4,5,6,77,8,12,0,9];
let max = values.reduce(_.ary(Math.max, 2),0);
```

Comment: Too quick, I was in progress of writing the same exact thing... :D

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious, but I was totally blocked with it, thank you